# Method With @PathVariable In SpringBoot Returns Empty Response

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to write a method which takes a @PathVariable parameter and redirects user to a jsp file.

```
@Controller
public class MainController 
{

    @RequestMapping("/user/{customerId}")
    // http://localhost:8080/Test/user/5
    public String getCustomerById(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId, Model model) 
    {
            model.addAttribute("customer_id", customerId);
            // this is the user_details.jsp file, I need to show this jsp file to visitor
            return "user_details";
    }
}
```

When I try to navigate http://localhost:8080/SpringBlog/user/5 It's showing me an empty response. (Nothing Even In Page Source)

When I looked into Spring output console, it's showing me the following message when I'm trying to navigate :

> 2017-07-19 13:24:56.191 ERROR 6772 --- [io-8080-exec-75]
>
> o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter
>
> Cannot forward to error page for request [/user/5] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

I've already tried following parameter descriptions as the followings :

> @PathVariable(value="customerId") String customerId
>
> @PathVariable(name="customerId") String customerId
>
> @PathVariable("customerId") String customerId
>
> @PathVariable String customerId

None of them worked, always empty response with same error message.

I'm sure that all files are in correct place, in my MainController Class
I have several methods with No Parameters, RequestParams, etc.. all of them working as expected. But if I want to create a RequestMapping with @PathVariable, it always returns empty response and same error message in the output console.

But if I try same approach with @RestController it's working as expected:

```
@RestController
public class RestApi
{
    // http://localhost:8080/Test/api/user/56
    // Is Working, Returns Hello 56 As Response
    @RequestMapping("api/user/{customerId}")
    public String apiTest(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId)
    {
        return "Hello "+customerId; 
    }
}
```

What am I missing ?

Application Details :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
JVM 1.8.0_131-b11
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the name you are going to return is correct, I mean "user_details"? Did you defined ".jsp" postfix in application.properties?

Comment: Hi, I added some extra details about application. Yes, I have user_details.jsp in the folder with other jsp files, Every method works normally which does not have a parameter as @PathVariable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please , check your application.properties file ...

prefix and suffix

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: (Where are jsp files) Example /WEB-INF/ or / 
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: spring.mvc.view.prefix: / Solved My Problem. It's A MUST to Add This Prefix If you're Going To Use PathVariables, Else It'll Try To Reach JSP Files Along With The Path Variables Such As localhost/app/user/5/user_details!

Answer (score 2):

The annotation `@RestController` automatically adds the `@ResponseBody` to your methods.

What `@ResponseBody` does is to bind the outgoing returned value to the HTTP response body using a `HttpMessageConverter`. If you don't add either the `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody` annotation then Spring will try to resolve that to a view, commonly a JSP page.

So in your case Spring is trying to find the view matchin `"Hello"+customerId` instead of printing out the result of `"Hello"+customerId`.

So you're using the @PathVariable annotation correctly. :)

You can read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

Comment: Daniel, what I want to do : using PathVariable in my Controller and send user_details.jsp as the result. I just type RestController Class  as an example I don't want to use it, I need PathVariable methods in Controller class which returns correct responses

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@Controller` annotation then you need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation for binding the outgoing returned value to the HTTP response body. So your code with `@Controller` should look like:

```
@Controller
public class MainController 
{

    @RequestMapping("/user/{customerId}")
    @ResponseBody
    // http://localhost:8080/Test/user/5
    public ModelAndView getCustomerById(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId, ModelAndView model) 
    {
            model.addAttribute("customer_id", customerId);
            // this is the user_details.jsp file, I need to show this jsp file to visitor
            model.setViewName("user_details");
            return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Krishna, when I add ResponseBody annotation, it's just giving user_details string as response.  I need to show user_details.jsp.

Comment: You need to use ModelAndView object instead. Refer to my updated answer. Try it now.

Comment: Unfortunately :(     https://paste.ubuntu.com/25125232/  Please see the following link what I've done and what I've get

Comment: Could you check whether the control is reaching this controller by running in debug mode with breakpoints?

Comment: Please check the following image : https://i.hizliresim.com/r209Bm.png         I got parameter values in method. But when model is returned, I got same error message in Console and empty response in web browser

Comment: Why did you add `@GetMapping` annotation here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149601/discussion-between-krishna-kuntala-and-emir-civas).